# Unity: Convert PNG Texture2D to byte[] array and back. Then display

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am  writing an Android app in Unity C# which implements an sqlite database. The program tries to store pictures in the database with relevant info.

I am trying to solve the following steps to solve a piece of this:

1. Display a png as 'texture2d' located in the Resources folder - achieved
2. Convert the png 'texture2d' to a byte array (to save to a db)  -???
3. Convert from byte array back into a 'Texture2D' and display it (PROBLEMS HERE).

At step 3, when trying to convert the byte array back into a 'texture2d', something goes wrong.  A red question mark is displayed instead of the png.

The variable 'img' is supposed to hold the texture converted back from the byte array, but trying to display 'img' just shows a big red question mark. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public byte[] imageData;    //image byte array that wil hold texture-converted-to-png
/******************/

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    /************************/

    // load texture from resource folder
    Texture2D photo = new Texture2D(355, 355);  //declare texture2d to hold pic from resources folder
    Texture2D img = new Texture2D(355, 355);    //holds texture converted back from byte array 

    photo = Resources.Load("eeyore") as Texture2D; //load pic from resources folder into texture2d

    imageData = photo.EncodeToPNG();    //Encode texture to PNG to save as Byte Array in database
    img.LoadImage(imageData);           //try to change byte array back into a texture2d to display
    img.Apply();                        //same thing happens if this is here or not

    GameObject rawImage = GameObject.Find("RawImage"); //Find the 'RawImage' 
    rawImage.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = img;   //BIG RED ? HERE ...set a texture to the raw image ('photo' works,'img' doesnt)

    /*************************/
    StartSync();
}
```

this is when i display 'photo':
[image]

this is when i display 'img': 
[image]

Comment: its.png.  But an extension is not needed. When i bring 'eeyore' in its saved in 'photo'.  In the next to last line, if i use 'photo' instead of 'img', the image will display.

Comment: i try to change 'photo' to an array of bytes[], then back to a texture2d called 'img'.  'img' will not display, but its 'parent photo' will.

Comment: and my pics are in the 'Resources' folder

Comment: photo isn't null.  If i try to display 'photo' it shows up just fine.  After trying to convert 'photo' to a byte[] array, then back it won't show.

Comment: yes correct.  that line works.

Comment: same red question mark when i encode to JPG.  The original pic is a png if that matters.  It seems weird to turn a png into a texture2d and back into a png.

Comment: Unity version = 5.6, platform = windows, problem is in editor. the project build just fine.

Comment: IM not sure what you mean. I can import an image from a folder and display it.  After i try to convert the image to a byte[] array and back, a question mark appears instead of my image. Visual Studio never throws errors. I just don't get the image back from img.LoadImage(imageData) like i should.

Comment: ok. i built it into a exe.  I ran the .exe and got the same thing ..a big red question mark.

Comment: ...and if the problem is still there? what were you gonna say???  This problem is kicking my ass and i'd be finished with the project if it weren't for this.

Comment: always update unity unless you have a very big reason not to do so. I always wonder why people always fear updating, it is easy even for large projects

Comment: Its updated. How should i send the scene

Comment: I had this problem once. Have you made sure the image is readable? EncodeToPNG should throw an exception if it is not. If there are no exceptions it's likely returning null. You can make it readable if you click the eeyore image in the Unity Editor, and make sure in the import settings (in the Inspector) that "Read/Write Enabled" in the advanced section is checked. If you pass null to img.LoadImage, and then assign the result to rawImage.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture, you'll get the question mark image you have.

Answer (score -1):

```
    byte[] vs = new byte[] { };

    string[] newbytesString = downloadId.Split(new string[] { "/" }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for(int kl=0;kl<newbytesString.Length;kl++)
    {
        vs[kl] = (byte)int.Parse(newbytesString[kl]);
    }
    icon.sprite = downloadedImage;
    downloadedImage.texture.LoadImage(vs);
    icon.sprite.texture.LoadImage(vs);
    icon.sprite.texture.Apply();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public string downloadId;
public Sprite downloadedImage;
public Image icon;

public void DownloadAFile()
{
     Debug.LogError("DownloadAFile()");
     // Get the url associated with the uploadId
     /*new GetUploadedRequest().SetUploadId(downloadId).Send((response) =>
     {
         //pass the url to our coroutine that will accept the data
         StartCoroutine(DownloadImage(response.Url));
     });*/

    byte[] vs = new byte[] { };

    string[] newbytesString = downloadId.Split(new string[] { "/" }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for(int kl=0;kl<newbytesString.Length;kl++)
    {
        vs[kl] = (byte)int.Parse(newbytesString[kl]);
    }
    icon.sprite = downloadedImage;
    downloadedImage.texture.LoadImage(vs);
    icon.sprite.texture.LoadImage(vs);
    icon.sprite.texture.Apply();
}
```

Answer (score -8):

Try this:

```
string mybytes = "25521625522401674707370011001010025521906708667658777998101220131211111225181915202926313029262828323646393234443528284055414448495252523139576156506046515250255219067199912111224131324503328335050505050505050505050505050505050505050505050505050505050505050505050505050505050505050505050505050255192017801300130313402171317125519603100151111110000000012345678910112551960181160213324355440011251230417518334965619819773411320501291451618356617719321822092403651981141309102223242526373839404142525354555657586768697071727374838485868788899099100101102103104105106115116117118119120121122131132133134135136137138146147148149150151152153154162163164165166167168169170178179180181182183184185186194195196197198199200201202210211212213214215216217218225226227228229230231232233234241242243244245246247248249250255196031103111111111000000123456789101125519601811702124434754401211901231745334961865817971131934501298206614516117719393551822402198114209102236522253724123242526383940414253545556575867686970717273748384858687888990991001011021031041051061151161171181191201211221301311321331341351361371381461471481491501511521531541621631641651661671681691701781791801811821831841851861941951961971981992002012022102112122132142152162172182262272282292302312322332342422432442452462472482492502552180123102173170630240106401621531631952184321152221285548942491691740868431194188211211971807950238362922087851488680206201471291842451741117542183202237209651112101802258718621222412112169142185236421083810817013184199215816872167109289612621503920372129168131281171671332519325310684791981649206104176171326024042182168159241411852425501501021808514572521061901681522101101431114117017316011756831242272357297972192116718916114249614291697715311211318015974207152214230331362101081731311662062171946255012910175531482321211292550520016615292206217245162172109111672498178236158995520811541381671622514971169169239192911660965952298520918218615967861171254149184302584254148116332385978662105461481071631383215124612824421621617212550622141581402252419148936961237184131502188730134133184722116924525310610131832021371845725084137233193521373769317414447601172396631421232121685620042240106190174184209174200237111274219013924215417117117525273175492550608818435146176136139881352513417519812855215541239864594031165916820774203169125513849156852241528070115237801961902231499382101002341131834019110615513124721924825323216823815550158571152522321679818057234411238228101621722023336105491592252420218403177208333121749228224177233239891221961501822479117216519620212696164224319923586382121341531631931101362221161451005510120511568146114126180911695452617716848101101561421562261647794242181632071241312121562141246449193865723287181911437319018563185182146762478523576441072191201342412315322827942195165116186941791071681831501411781125020918395195214184731801712519524521421017521377878715021411714575713415720212217751138824520019342127741731711752527311024125506020017062272141341731068524018317253225140110247211651711401041831241272035176150115177392024859116171721912531061423324214025502501702024612321470132177129914320217357219191713113353935697781861458625141152421541001561532536243205201011271881041645916315016214021019902245242012147521692041392542401606925386225238462010943281041750491561410618118859216192115338162239372091023614012419021353160198208715215528861861577812910311133218998635158691188610433251170209928102291245615955394254181216108216188117355218153178479119411012216217624725172111202487429741972225621459164271451281981251711237212519630132288615723413513515822141165165200105941991312481142269113109355793205229186145941331721401041831272452042152912310924695251791683625316029170611071812152326452232531155393123718520768112163175227866519257352121541721528525237854711168171888116172250150911841911422201141952431724571944719164715134505986612132361471834411823116582987953737414715963252245127251232209801265283178301302651692091378264187166792471705815421610222511521915458121811221281961727322275269111871007317923382921741092012443221320551761072385599111111901508485205296147180229192345255712691182223207168168401321861426417496232113217194210121146171122222002509921018612713512319022158144821811366527420017561197232188104109239254206217198101305108219381753019511312414716712649154204241471312522538123119752672219151107991111681741317320945226181711402002061711342202291352358517419653173206105244226222585536124158641511599414912793312413618861252179862297924815717999149128169252901711071635821239253115538121619412717203222491255623392246175413617411323791140223413921018518977195752341152051001834619897341522122271974917020966100122254148816948221472356920152131215316725022412556783218103206621521612363565134232153123145214180116591311220314282242141061241951427788183221202041895913814616223620615988188681820188913524173223134236115113385061141232151360222107100156224961031811171581718218913373911477156141921682424122320452051421758121219523417310932192108718453163104222691711211092421762288630171166188162431614114622632317724446214910239971072013535165903477881711410018418518563198219872326325024917021823061311251584911261902042132301020621521647135245141912342724985165161200229119115131151841831728121157631841071571851567333971581251051982492077105242441976692633611917223610815325110122210281191672811722613055912139208415230148831148822112102212282281247169164162222194109452002348824431810512120108282301571281289611522215943234795598220871016739381721552161571633331353113310015039173624637301482491084323410854230577031150107163208238101183194253178228103144856223324653205198761209651143210186205151961621817035149318419769181541402092105319720215217469208158505418617810999239199252524117923420866202178181702202383138124792531681932132656115146204491872338812634100911691748225269192236122215703015415617220676931038943967212041191119055872912683154200241275910424712830601342051152475124955542352714914818459148224227189651701062474977451712052316542214071356011717415415211929153201751920511010116919896113732231542321106049401828996112881749038601431612550261941542510922310017718010320814010218542821483016823716794157692381871519617989244249371124332447917617011141201741436613673165952511362519174231176796110197681501971972211805920324652841587525120974197115332461861241514873504818242381062371646651912411821862550116246531237818310712022741271722011082550421451796154114131229145115143661553232211195217381211814913201165242511631784512342502532132058515420515096128103118641741613313117359612420914026134918124617111472714212742210881162091561131097422271501821421955657218797974341281902361178115687664519417816995188178962146882173190162174126224962812311917239696929202351852221981421571104661947256174183702101627052135510313086178159777539911711193083124192123261873913617323696391164199106110714281179581634317314154247811317218114205190102249981431875524814245197106195116918621011491342272347323015512211221179106551747517619413120923219210179205207153118101613583392448125312726244112244253156110247103155941101817545151230321512062157514866272258021925501651071552195841506365852373197185144245812751691481908487501037102208126180115931759114321721759118177168250148175126194351503244126128154214759110713983121681781981520623922024721925502141749979442115114292123812579218640791478138891116188170158149211732432212002281967121721915175162331221272162118913311952662132185461215211951332241254321110839138251146315455510013217727208142707174224117107104237537513616171881311472618380167165112982402381515310812224287118018612315324924752832412376911321624478186223152236024181201255031205255092205208718619020124250248153161312222550128472421661832502166322495202138437117713024813610325509111125502254852047925503118125104162185431581341999170181102623113544792032359222013215515878121312061384320715119811971224103711702411652011426285254117138126237231213104162189261891559132401242022081271991892072081275896255014389632229040174941999022115415448251106313612790158209137149178792225281931161827121109217173111254183240172175214224911215612250227222138437679240153134152532252818120819425244103255217";

byte[] bytes =mybytes;
```

Comment: how is this helpful? does it answer the question?

Comment: What the hell ?